# Does Outland on the Xbox 360 autosave before boss fights?

Tags: xbox-live-arcade

Like the question says: does the game autosave before boss fights?

I don't want to fight it now, so i wonder if i can turn the console off and return later.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. :-)

The control points in the levels are no real savegames, though. If you got to one of them and turn off the console, you have to restart the level.